# When should I use: I did, had done or have done?

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses

Please explain when I should use:

- *I did* vs. *I had done* or
- *I had done* vs. *I have done*?

Sometimes I tend to get confused about which one to use. Thanks.

Comment: Those are all grammatical phrases, and don't mean the same thing. You should use them whenever you intend to mean what they do.

Comment: IMHO, you should use [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) instead of this site for English-learning questions.  And even there you should **provide more context/background**, so people can better understand your question and thus better help you.